# What is the "+++ /tmp/security" line about?

Tags: freebsd, logs

On one particular FreeBSD (9.2) VM, the security log that's e-mailed out always contains a line like:

```
+++ /tmp/security.uOdQ7hEd  2015-01-31 03:01:21.000000000 -0500
```

While googling, I get lots of hits on people with errors immediately after it, but no explanation as to what it is.  I do not have any errors after it.  Also, none of the other FreeBSD VMs that we have throw that line in the e-mail.

My only guess so far is that it might be some special logging function that we turned on at some point.  I really don't know what it would be though, these VMs are all pretty standard, so I'm curious as to what might be different on this one.  Also, since 9.2 is near EOL I'd like to make sure that we don't miss anything special during our migration to a new version.

Comment: Just as a general point on improving the question, does there appear to be some pattern to the context that surrounds it? Also how is it emailed out, is it a script you guys wrote or an application?

Comment: That line only occurs on the one box and happens every day.  It's e-mailed out by the default FreeBSD system scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `periodic` script sends the output from certain of the security checks to tempfiles in `/tmp`. The line you are asking about is a `diff` header - and the line before it in the email will tell you which of the security checks generated it. The scripts live in `/etc/periodic/security`, and they're just shell scripts, so you can dig around in there to get a better understanding of what they do. In this case, it's probably generated by `700.kernelmsg`, and the fact there's nothing after it is a good sign!

The `diff` header is created when the function `check_diff()` in `/etc/periodic/security/security.functions` is called by the individual checks.

You'd need to compare the `/etc/periodic.conf` files on a couple of your VMs to work out what the differences are. The `periodic` subsystem's default config lives in `/etc/defaults/periodic.conf`, and the one in `/etc` overrides those default settings.

This is perfectly normal, and nothing to worry about. It's a sign that your `periodic` subsystem is working normally.